# how to get value of bind_result() on another page

Tags: php, mysql

on `db_handler.php` page

```
public function getAllUserList($user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT list_id,name,date_created FROM list  WHERE user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $list = $stmt->bind_result($list_id,$name,$date_created);
    $stmt->close();
    return $list;
}
```

on `index.php`

```
$result = $db->getAllUserList($user_id);
while ($result->fetch()) {
            $tmp = array();
            $tmp["id"] = $list_id;
            $tmp["list_name"] = $name;
            $tmp["createdAt"] = $date_created;
            array_push($response["lists"], $tmp);
        }
```

its giving fatal error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

previously I was using `$stmt->get_result()` method instead of bind_result but it start throwing error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   `mysqli_stmt::get_result().`

if I use  `while ($result->fetch())` on `dbhandler.php` page it working fine. but it gives error on `index.php`

Comment: Try with comment this line `$stmt->close();` form your code!!

Comment: still giving the same error after commenting $stmt->close();

Comment: bind_result() has bool return type whereas get_result has mysqli_result return type that's why values can assign to any variable like but  values cant be stored in bind_result. there must be another method for this problem.

Comment: Just but some more effort in finding a solution on your own, like reading the language documentation for the methods you use for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return `$stmt` rather than `$list` and not close the statement (until after you've fetched all the results).

You'll also need to bring `bind_result` out from the function as the variables are scoped.

```
public function getAllUserList($user_id) {
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT list_id,name,date_created FROM list  WHERE user_id = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt;
}

...

$result = $db->getAllUserList($user_id);

$result->bind_result($list_id,$name,$date_created);
```

`bind_result` (and so `$list`) returns a boolean to indicate success or failure, not the result set, and so you're trying to call `fetch()` on a `true` (or `false`).

Comment: Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

  Details

Type: ErrorException
Code: 2
Message: mysqli_stmt::fetch() [mysqli-stmt.fetch]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object
new error found

Comment: thank you for the solution. you explained with a ease. thank you once again